# App Bar not filling the top of the page MUI MATERIAL

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styles

I am using MUI MATERIAL.

I got an
[image: AppBar]
It has a padding on the top,right,left of the page.

I want the App Bar to be at the very top of the page.
I tried using classes but it does not work.

components/AppBar/index.js

```
import * as React from "react";
import AppBar from "@mui/material/AppBar";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Toolbar from "@mui/material/Toolbar";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import IconButton from "@mui/material/IconButton";
import MenuIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Menu";
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: "#130f40",
    margin: 0
  }
});

export default function ButtonAppBar() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
      <AppBar position="static" className={classes.root}>
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            size="large"
            edge="start"
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="menu"
            sx={{ mr: 2 }}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h6" component="div" sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
            News
          </Typography>
          <Button color="inherit">Login</Button>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add  [CssBaseline](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-css-baseline) at the top level of your app to get rid of the space around the `AppBar` component. It will apply style rules from [normalize.css](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css) which includes `margin:0` on the `body` element which is the reason for this gap.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';

export default function MyApp() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <CssBaseline />
      {/* The rest of your application */}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: `CssBaseline ` comes with mui and is not a separate depandancy

Comment: Thank for clarifying @Dmitriif, doing a better search i found it in the MUI docs